# @media queries - why does css rule overrule another?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

im using a media query for `max-width: 768px;`
and have put the css rule for an element as `left: 80px;`

then BENEATH this i have another media query targeting max width of 800px
and in that i have the same element set to `left: 94px;`

However when i change the screen size to the smaller 768 and check with firebug the rule of `left: 80px;` is crossed out and the `left: 94px;` is being followed.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you show us your media selectors and the CSS rule in question?

Comment: Because `max-width` `800px` override `768px` because you call it after 768px so use `min-width` in place of it

Comment: doh! that was rather simple. Thank you Arpit.

Comment: First show us your code.  Second the ordering of your media queries is the main factor here.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Add that as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `max-width:800px` override `768px` because you call it after `768px` so use `min-width` in place of it

Answer (score 1):

Because `max-width 800px` override `768px` because you call it after `768px` so use `min-width` in place of it – [Arpit Srivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306308/arpit-srivastava)